# In QCalender widget, How to show the calender for foreign date other than Gregorian calendar?

Tags: qt, qt5

Is there a way to change the in-built Gregorian calender date data to other calender date like Hindu calender, etc in QCalender widget in QT ? All the functions of QCalender are great but i would like it to display different calender date system.

Comment: yeah i read that too. but it also mentioned: "It can read the current date from the system clock." I was wondering if we could modify where the QDate gets its date data from, this should be possible. or any simpler way to do this.

Comment: I'm afraid I confused [`QCalendar`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qcalendar.html) with `QCalendarWidget`. The former was added in Qt 5.14. The snapshots in the concerning issue ticket [Add support for Calendar System other than Gregorian; first the Jalali Calendar](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-58404?focusedCommentId=349401&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel) let me believe that this should affect [`QCalendarWidget`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qcalendarwidget.html) as well but I couldn't find a resp. hint in the latter. (Not yet?).

Comment: May be, this feature is still a little bit new and you have to wait a while until it's stable and public available.

Comment: @Scheff There are some pending changes that will [adapt QCalendarWidget and QDateTimeEdit to support a choice of calendar](https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtbase/+/270040/3). However, I'm not sure what version those changes will land in, because I can't find a corresponding issue on the tracker. This all seems to be part of a larger effort to [improve locale support in Qt5](https://wiki.qt.io/Locale_Support_in_Qt_5) (see the [section there on QCalendar](https://wiki.qt.io/Locale_Support_in_Qt_5#QCalendar)).